# using loops to create feature tests in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Im trying to write a feature tests that test multiple variables being passed to the same method.
I need my test to look like the following:

```
puts "station 1 to station 2"
new_card
@card.touch_out(@station1)
@card.touch_out(@station2)
print_card_details
```

Im using 8 different stations so I am looping through an array [1..8] like so:

```
stations.each do |station_numberA|
    stations.each do |station_numberB|
        puts "station #{station_numberA} to #{station_numberB}"
        new_card
        stationA = @station+station_numberA
        stationB = @station+station_numberB
        @card.touch_in(stationA)
        @card.touch_out(stationB)
        print_card_details
    end
end
```

can anybody show me a way of making this work? The problem seems to be in how to pass an instance variable to the touch_in/out methods.

Comment: Where do the instance variables come from?

Comment: You're not asserting anything.